# UIPickerView prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uistoryboardsegue, social-framework

I am creating a client. selects an account and the account passes (through segue). wanted to know how it does it.
obs ** data passing is an array (of account) of a picker selected by the User.

This returns the pickerview:

```
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
  ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:row]; 
  return [acct username];
}
```

have to pass the option (array) selected by the User to another view to use as Account (Twitter)

I managed to do it once with TableView (but I thought the horrible interface) and decided to make pickerview. the problem only in passing this data (below), is not equal to tableview

Comment: Requesting you to provide more information.

Comment: This returns the pickerview:
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:row];
  
    return [acct username];
    
}

Comment: have to pass the option (array) selected by the User to another view to use as Account (Twitter)